# What is meant by $\mathbb{Z}^0$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, notation

What is the additive group $\mathbb{Z}^0$? Is it the trivial group? I can't seem to find an answer to this online.

Comment: Context would help.

Comment: I thought this was standard notation but if not I guess we can take the context to be the statement of the Fundamental Theorem of Finitely Generated Abelian Groups.

Comment: With no context whatsoever, I would also say that $\mathbb Z^0$ is just the trivial group. However, I would say $0$ in the group exponent is at the very least uncommon, so an author might have given it a special meaning.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The group $G^n$ consists of $n$-tuples with elements in $G$, or equivalently functions from a $n$-element set to $G$, with component-wise operations.

So then, $G^0$ would be the set of functions from the empty set to $G$. We have component-wise operations, but with no components to operate on that's irrelevant. There is only one empty function, and this becomes the trivial group of one element.